# Conventional Landau orders and non-conventional orders in the pseudogap of cuprate

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, topological-order, fermi-liquids

> 1. **What kind of conventional Landau orders have been seen in the pseudogap phase of cuprate?** Such as Spin-Density Wave, Charge-Density Wave, etc? What are the most influential/representative journal Refs for the **experimental observations and theoretical justifications?**

-

> 2. **What kind of non-conventional orders have been seen in the pseudogap phase of cuprate?** Such as topological orders, symmetry-protected orders, fractionalizations, spin-liquids and what else?  What are the most influential/representative journal Refs for the **experimental observations and theoretical justifications?**